# How to verify the consumer (REST API)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, pact

It is not clear how to verify the consumer pact with Mock assertion

1. In our case , we want to verify the consumer pact .
2. Our API's would allow the user to create Order and update order , etc
3. Hence the OrderIds were auto generated , and the consumer pact will always have the same Id, and i tried several methods (JUnit 5, junit , etc)
4. But we could make it work.

My expectation is :

1. The consumer pact request will get incepted , and our provider pact will return mock response.

Any suggestions or samples ?

We have tried the below samples ,

https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit5

https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit

Answer (score 0):

**For Dynamic response you can try pact concept called Matchers :**

1. JSON Response : You can use PactDslJsonBody class to skip matching of ids and simply check it's type i.e. Integer, String...

https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/matching

2. XML : You can use PactXmlBuilder class for the xml tags value. In XML if you want to skip matching of a particular tag then we can simply remove that tag from consumer side XML.

[https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/blob/7ff6491a0923e4709a8f78ab5451a99989559712/consumer/junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/junit/xml/TodoXmlTest.java](https://%5Bhttps://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/matching%5D%5B1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/matching)

**Response content-type is very important to use Matchers concept for xml API's response type must be text/xml or application/xml respectively for json it should be text/json or application/json**

Comment: Hello , 
     I appreciate your answer ,

Comment: But my question has been understood differently. Let me explain with more details  1. We have Spring Boot application which is handles Orders , In this case i would like to take POST and PUT api consumer pacts for an instance(When the consumer provides a pact file which contains OrderId in the URL so our application at the runtime will never ensure the same OrderId because it has been generated uniquely all the time)   -  To handle this scinario i have tried several mocking methods but nothing worked as such.(Because there are so many library incompatibility)

Comment: Could you please share Consumer and Provider side code snippet. We can analyze it